# Count the number of time that we increase a given Date range

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-formula

I want to count the number of times (given a range Date) that I move a date (forward) given also an interval, let's say, **6 months**.

---

#### Example:

**The range:**

*Start date:  2019/08/05*

*End date:    2020/08/05*

**Interval:**    6 Months

- 1st time:  2019/08/05 + 6 Months = **2020/02/05**
- 2nd time:  2020/02/05 + 6 Months = **2020/08/05**

For this case, the output = **2**

---

I want to print my desirable output in a specific cell.

I wanted to build a VBA using the syntax:

**DateAdd ( interval, number, date )**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FirstDate As Date    ' Declare variables.
    Dim IntervalType As Integer
    Dim Number As Integer
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim TempDate As Date

    Dim i As Integer

    IntervalType = "m" ' "m" specifies MONTHS as interval.

    FirstDate = Cells(1, 1).Value
    EndDate = Cells(1, 2).Value
    Number = Cells(1, 3).Value  ' "Number" For the syntax DateAdd.

    i = 1
    Do Until TempDate = EndDate
        TempDate= DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, FirstDate)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Range("D1").Value = i
End Sub
```

But I'm getting this error:

[image: VBA Error]

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Hi @rohrl77 in  line 13 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to assign a String to and Integer data type. Change `IntervalType` to a String.

```
Sub DateTest()
    Dim FirstDate As Date    ' Declare variables.
    Dim IntervalType As String
    Dim Number As Integer
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim TempDate As Date
    Dim i As Integer

    IntervalType = "m" ' "m" specifies MONTHS as interval.
    FirstDate = Cells(1, 1).Value
    EndDate = Cells(1, 2).Value
    Number = Cells(1, 3).Value  ' "Number" For the syntax DateAdd.

    ' If number is not greater than zero an infinite loop will happen.
    If Number <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "Number needs to be greater than 0", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    i = 1
    Do Until TempDate = EndDate
       If i <= 1 Then
           TempDate = DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, FirstDate)
       Else
           TempDate = DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, TempDate)
        End If
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print i
    Loop
    Range("D1").Value = i - 1
End Sub
```

Also, You were running an infinite Loop with TempDate always looping from the `FirstDate` variable.

Also, if your `Number` is less than or equal to zero then you will get an infinite loop.

Also, the `Else` gets rid of the overflow error. Without it, the `TempDate` would reset after every loop.

Comment: Hi Miles, thanks. Now it looks better, INow If I chose for example 25-Jul-19 as start date End Date 25-Jul-20 (frequency 6M) End date its works fine, but if I change the End Date, let say 25-Jul-21  I get an error: "Overflow" it doesn't say too much, what can be causing it? Thanks again

Comment: Lorenzo, I updated the code and it should run without the overflow error now.

Comment: Hi Miles, sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your time too.